# JavaScript: querySelectorAll & classList toggle not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

I have a number of buttons that I want to switch the class `active` on when another button is selected and also toggle the button when the button with the `active` class is selected again (i.e. removing the class).

Also, `this` is correctly returning the selected element when I `console.log` it.

The line `this.classList.toggle('active');` is adding the class but not removing it. Any idea why?

```
    var controls = document.querySelectorAll('.controls > button');

    for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) {
        controls[i].addEventListener('click', btnClick, false);
    }

    function btnClick() {
        [].forEach.call(controls, function(el) {
            // Remmove active class from all buttons
            el.classList.remove('active');
        });

        this.classList.toggle('active');
    }
```

Comment: You seem to be reinventing radio buttons.

Comment: I know what you're saying. So a better approach would be to use radio buttons but style them in a way so the label is getting the styling and the radio button UI should be hidden? In this case, they should look like buttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT

According to your comment, you want to be able to toggle a button off. I updated the answer to use this behaviour.

```js
var controls = document.querySelectorAll('.controls > button');

// you can use forEach here too
[].forEach.call(controls, el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', btnClick, false)
})

function btnClick() {
  // use Array function for lexical this
  [].forEach.call(controls, el => {
    // except for the element clicked, remove active class
    if (el !== this) el.classList.remove('active');
  });

  // toggle active on the clicked button
  this.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
button {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  outline: 0;
}

button.active {
  background: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="controls">
  <button class="active">A</button>
  <button>B</button>
  <button>C</button>
  <button>D</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If you select A, and then select A again, it doesn't become deselected. That's my issue.

Comment: Well that's because you always re-toggle 'active' as the last line in `btnClick`

Comment: If you select A and then select B, should A turn off ?

Comment: Duh me! Because they always get removed, then obviously it toggles off again. Don't know why I didn't see that... suggestion to update the code? if a new button is selected the active class should move, but if the active button is selected, the class should be toggled.

Comment: Yes, and also if you select A when A is active, A should turn off.

Answer (score 2):

You first remove the class from **all** the elements. Then you toggle it on one of them. Since you just removed it from all of them, that always adds it back.

Exclude the selected one from the list you are removing the class from.

```
function btnClick() {

    var target = this;

    [].forEach.call(controls, function(el) {
        if (target !== el) {
            el.classList.remove('active');
        }
    });

    target.classList.toggle('active');
}
```